# Concatenate multiple video files alongside delayed audio files

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

I am currently working on a utility that is responsible for pulling audio and video files from the cloud and merging them together via FFMPEG. As I am new to FFMPEG, I am going to split the question into an FFMPEG part and a C# part just so people can answer either 1 part or the other (or both!).

FFMPEG Part

Currently, I have a working FFMPEG arg if there is only 1 video file present and it needs to be merged with multiple files.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mkv -i input1.mka -i input2.mka -i input3.mka -i input4.mka -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=0s:all=1[a1pad];[2:a]adelay=20s:all=1[a2pad];[3:a]adelay=30s:all=1[a3pad];[4:a]adelay=40s:all=1[a4pad];[a1pad][a2pad][a3pad][a4pad]amix=inputs=4:weights=1|1|1|1[aout]" -map [aout] -map 0:0 output4.mkv
```

The delays you see in there are determined by subtracting the start time of each file from the start time of the earliest created audio or video file. I know that if I wanted to create a horizontal stack of multiple videos, i could just do

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mkv -i input1.mka -i input2.mkv -i input2.mka -i input3.mka -i input4.mka
-filter_complex 
"[2:v]tpad=start_duration=120:color=black[vpad]; 
 [3:a]adelay=120000:all=1[a2pad]; 
 [4:a]adelay=180000:all=1[a3pad];
 [5:a]adelay=200000:all=1[a4pad]; 
 [0:v][vpad]hstack=inputs=2[vout]; 
 [1:a][a2pad][a3pad][a4pad]amix=inputs=4:weights=1|1|1|1[aout]" 
 -map [vout] -map [aout] 
 output.mkv
```

but what I want to do is both keep those delays for the audio and video files AND concatenate (not stack) those videos, how would i go about doing that?

C# Part

You see that giant arg up there? The utility is supposed to generate that based on a List of recordings. Here is the model.

```
List<FileModel> _records;
public class FileModel {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string FileType { get; set; }
  public string StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

The utility has to then go through that list and create the arg (as seen in the FFMPEG part) to be executed by the Xabe.FFMPEG package. The way i was thinking to approach this is to basically create 2 string builders. 1 string builder will be responsible for dealing with the inputs, the other string builder. Here is what i have so far

```
private async Task CombineAsync()
    {
        var minTime = _records.Min(y => Convert.ToDateTime(y.StartTime));
        var frontBuilder = new StringBuilder("-y ");
        var middleBuilder = new StringBuilder("-filter_complex \"");
        var endString = $" -map [vout] -map [aout] {_folderPath}\\CombinedOutput.mkv";

        for (var i = 0; i < _records.Count; i++)
        {
            var type = _records[i].FileType.ToLower();
            var delay = (Convert.ToDateTime(_records[i].StartTime).Subtract(minTime)).TotalSeconds;
            frontBuilder.Append($"-i {_folderPath + "\\" + _records[i].Id} ");
            var addColon = i != _records.Count - 1 ? ";" : "";
            middleBuilder.Append(type.Equals("video") ? $"[{i}:v]tpad=start_duration={delay}:color=black[v{i}pad]{addColon} " : $"[{i}:a]adelay={delay}s:all=1[a{i}pad]{addColon} ");
        }
        middleBuilder.Append("\"");
        Console.WriteLine(frontBuilder.ToString() + middleBuilder.ToString() + endString);
        // var args = frontBuilder + middleBuilder + endString;
        // try
        // {
        //     var conversionResult = await FFmpeg.Conversions.New().Start(args);
        //     Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(conversionResult));
        // }
        // catch (Exception e)
        // {
        //     Console.WriteLine(e);
        // }
    }
```

1. Is this the correct way to go about building the argument out?
2. How in god's name do i get something like this in there, since it relies on naming and total count for the piping and inputs=

   ```
     [0:v][vpad]hstack=inputs=2[vout]; // This part will change for video concatenation depending on what gets answered above
     [1:a][a2pad][a3pad][a4pad]amix=inputs=4:weights=1|1|1|1[aout]
   ```

Comment: @kesh I figured you would wanna take a crack at this :)

Comment: overlapping delay and concatenate are mutually exclusive. What do you mean by concatenate?

Comment: Ah crap, here i go again with my bad explanation. Basically i want the first video to play and then after whatever delay there is between the first video and the second video, the second video to play in place of the first one.

Comment: Look into how to use [ffconcat script and `-f concat`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) if input files are identical in their properties. Create 2 concat inputs, one for video and another for audio, and map them to video and audio streams of the output.

Comment: Yeah, the examples i've seen don't seem to have to deal with the delays and stuff like i have to so was wondering if you had a filtergraph designed to handle this like you had on the previous question.

Comment: If you want to use filtergraph instead, you just need `concat` filter and control the start and duration of your inputs via `-ss` and `-t` input options for each input.

Comment: What would be your recommendation? Because the number of audio and video files could vary.

Comment: Whichever one you can get a grip easier. Try filter route first.

Comment: Got any handy examples i can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In amix [document](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix)
`Note that this filter only supports float samples(the amerge and pan audio filters support many formats).`
Maybe your files is many format, try [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge)

For easy generate arguments with so much filters, try [FFmpegArgs](https://github.com/tqk2811/FFmpegArgs)

```
FFmpegArg ffmpegArg = new FFmpegArg().OverWriteOutput();
List<ImageMap> imageMaps = new List<ImageMap>();
List<AudioMap> audioMaps = new List<AudioMap>();
foreach (var item in _records)
{
    if (item.IsVideo)
    {
        imageMaps.Add(ffmpegArg.AddImageInput(new ImageFileInput(item.FilePath))
            .TpadFilter().StartDuration(item.Delay).MapOut);
    }
    else
    {
        audioMaps.Add(ffmpegArg.AddAudioInput(new AudioFileInput(item.FilePath))
            .AdelayFilter().Delays(item.Delay).All(true).MapOut);
    }
}
            
var imageMap = imageMaps.HstackFilter().MapOut;
var audioMap = audioMaps.AmergeFilter().MapOut;

ffmpegArg.AddOutput(new VideoFileOutput("out.mp4", imageMap, audioMap));
var result = ffmpegArg
    .Render(c => c
        .WithFFmpegBinaryPath("path to ffmpeg.exe")
        .WithWorkingDirectory("working dir"))
    .Execute();

result.EnsureSuccess();
```

Or by kesh comment

```
FFmpegArg ffmpegArg = new FFmpegArg().OverWriteOutput();
List<ImageMap> imageMaps = new List<ImageMap>();
List<AudioMap> audioMaps = new List<AudioMap>();
foreach (var item in _records)
{
    if (item.IsVideo)
    {
        imageMaps.Add(ffmpegArg.AddImageInput(new ImageFileInput(item.FilePath))
            .TpadFilter().StartDuration(item.Delay).MapOut);
    }
    else
    {
        audioMaps.Add(ffmpegArg.AddAudioInput(new AudioFileInput(item.FilePath)));
        //audioMaps.Add(ffmpegArg.AddAudioInput(new AudioFileInput(item.FilePath).SsPosition(item.Skip)));
    }
}
var imageMap = imageMaps.HstackFilter().MapOut;
var concatFilter = audioMaps.Select(x => new ConcatGroup(x)).ConcatFilter();

ffmpegArg.AddOutput(new VideoFileOutput("out.mp4", imageMap, concatFilter.AudioMapsOut.First()));
var result = ffmpegArg
    .Render(c => c
        .WithFFmpegBinaryPath("path to ffmpeg.exe")
        .WithWorkingDirectory("working dir"))
    .Execute();

result.EnsureSuccess();
```

Comment: I would say you should make overloads so it allows it to take in seconds, milliseconds, or timespan. What i noticed was was that the `|` did not appear if i gave it a timespan or seconds. I had to manually provide the string, as shown in pastebin for the pipe separator to appear.

Comment: It the params, you can put it as `.AdelayFilter().Delays(item.Delay,item.Delay)`

Comment: Great. Anyway to set this filter for a video file? [0:v]scale=iw:ih,setsar=1[v0]; Thank you btw, your project has been super helpful.

Comment: And anyway to suppress the reinit_filter?

Comment: `imageMap.ScaleFilter().W("iw").H("ih").MapOut.SetSarFilter().Ratio(1).MapOut`. What mean `reinit_filter`,  [this](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Commands-83)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71670473/ffmpeg-hstack-video-not-same-height. Here someone suggested add the -reinit_filter 0 so that it doesn't reinitialize filters.

Comment: Any chance to add the XFade filter? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553906/merging-multiple-video-files-with-ffmpeg-and-xfade-filter