# FFMPeg hstack video not same height

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am currently trying to horizontally stack multiple video files and receiving this error

```
[libvorbis @ 000001bb38f23a80] Queue input is backward in 
timerate=N/A speed=   0x
[libvorbis @ 000001bb38f23a80] Queue input is backward in 
timetrate= 799.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=3894 speed=15.7x
[libvorbis @ 000001bb38f23a80] Queue input is backward in 
timetrate= 798.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=3924 speed=15.8x
[Parsed_hstack_2 @ 000001bb3a3411c0] Input 1 height 480 does not 
match input 0 height 360.op=3929 speed=  16x
[Parsed_hstack_2 @ 000001bb3a3411c0] Failed to configure output pad 
on Parsed_hstack_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argumentError 
while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

This is my command.

```
ffmpeg -i RT05974d20e9550b89697b15f8bc3feb78.mkv -i RTb295d0534191e1acb22a45bb971a12e6.mka -i RTc2de0d06575c6c225b44dbce73104ed8.mkv -i RT3904b3a60273760ec9e9c181ea35bdc4.mka -i RT13386752138abbe5eb941da3f7fdfdc5.mka -i RTe31da14ad7c898ad8d8ce6bbafc5e387.mkv -i RT103bfe5f4b129860f69cd8e820f3a10b.mka -i RT2e5859b6a555070f3305735c698966d0.mka -filter_complex "[2:v]tpad=start_duration=120:color=black[vpad]; [3:a]adelay=120000:all=1[a2pad]; [4:a]adelay=150000:all=1[a3pad]; [5:v]tpad=start_duration=20:color=black[v2pad]; [6:a]adelay=200000:all=1[a5pad]; [7:a]adelay=240000:all=1[a6pad]; [0:v][vpad][v2pad]hstack=inputs=3[vout]; [1:a][a2pad][a3pad][a5pad][a6pad]amix=inputs=5:weights=1|1|1|1|1[aout]" -map [vout] -map [aout] output.mkv
```

I then also checked each file individually to make sure that their height and width were correct.

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0:s=x RT05974d20e9550b89697b15f8bc3feb78.mkv
640x480
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0:s=x RTc2de0d06575c6c225b44dbce73104ed8.mkv
640x480
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0:s=x RTe31da14ad7c898ad8d8ce6bbafc5e387.mkv
640x480
```

Full log pasted here - https://pastebin.com/0XEipXjA

Log when only two files are used - https://pastebin.com/AVYisBeh

Log when that first video file is not used (works) - https://pastebin.com/8YfHRsQ1

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: This is the cause: `Input 1 height 480 does not match input 0 height 360.. Add `scale` or `crop` filter(s) so the heights of all `hstack` inputs matches.

Comment: Right, that's the cause. I ran ffprobe and it's saying that the width and height of all the files is the same?

Comment: I just realized that... What happens if you swap the order of inputs?

Comment: [Parsed_hstack_0 @ 0000029d48242b80] Input 1 height 360 does not match input 0 height 480.op=498 speed=16.6x
[Parsed_hstack_0 @ 0000029d48242b80] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_hstack_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #2:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the first input's resolution is changing midway.

Suppress reinitializing filters, and force initial resolution using scale.

`ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -i RT05974d20e9550b89697b15f8bc3feb78.mkv -i RTb295d0534191e1acb22a45bb971a12e6.mka -i RTc2de0d06575c6c225b44dbce73104ed8.mkv -i RT3904b3a60273760ec9e9c181ea35bdc4.mka -i RT13386752138abbe5eb941da3f7fdfdc5.mka -i RTe31da14ad7c898ad8d8ce6bbafc5e387.mkv -i RT103bfe5f4b129860f69cd8e820f3a10b.mka -i RT2e5859b6a555070f3305735c698966d0.mka -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw:ih,setsar=1[v0];[2:v]tpad=start_duration=120:color=black[vpad]; [3:a]adelay=120000:all=1[a2pad]; [4:a]adelay=150000:all=1[a3pad]; [5:v]tpad=start_duration=20:color=black[v2pad]; [6:a]adelay=200000:all=1[a5pad]; [7:a]adelay=240000:all=1[a6pad]; [v0][vpad][v2pad]hstack=inputs=3[vout]; [1:a][a2pad][a3pad][a5pad][a6pad]amix=inputs=5:weights=1|1|1|1|1[aout]" -map [vout] -map [aout] output.mkv`

Comment: Thanks for your response Gyan. My question is, these files are being read from a list, so we won't know which file has this issue about the resolution changing midway. Should the scale and setsar filter be done for each video file?

Comment: If they are different inputs in the command, then yes. If it's part of a `-f concat` list, then ffmpeg sees it as one input, so not needed nor possible.

Comment: Use `color` filter input with default resolution, scale (save ratio) and draw it on center `color`. Use output for hstack. Don't forgot to change `setsar` ratio to 1. [example](https://gist.github.com/tqk2811/9f2f074fc973b5471b5f1526665c3e41)

Comment: @Gyan they are different inputs so like like i'll have to do that.

Comment: @TrươngQuốcKhánh, thank you for the example. How would I set the _reinit_filter 0 part using FFMpegArgs?

Comment: @Spartan117 Ah, for `FFmpegArgs` lib `new ImageFileInput("path").SetOption("-reinit_filter","0");`. All option for `FFmpegArg`, `Filter`, `Input`, `Output` are extend by `SetOption`, `SetFlag`, `SetOptionRange`

Comment: Thanks. Would ffmpeg -af "aresample=async=1 be considered a flag or an option? Coming from kesh's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71708414/ffmpeg-queue-input-backward-in-time/71712332?noredirect=1#comment126739109_71712332

Comment: `-af` is an option; `aresample=async=1` is its arg. Inside `aresample` is a filter and `async=1` is the resampling library option.